# Tooltip disappears in textbox when I press ESC in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, tooltip, mozilla

I'm using a tooltip tool called vtip in jquery.
When I hover over the textarea a tooltip appears but whenever I click escape (ESC) inside of the textarea, the next time I hover over the textarea, the tooltip disappears.

This only occurs in Firefox and works fine in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I guess disabling escape key should work in this case

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 27) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

edit: keycode for escape should be 27, and you can also try using keyup instead of keydown

Comment: The problem is that I'm using ESC as to cancel out of the textarea. So, I want to keep the ESC functionality but prevent it from killing my tooltip.

Thanks for you help!